# Saving statistics to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm relatively new to Google Analytics and would like to have some inputs.
So I have a web application that people can install to create a backup and can do restores as well. The application has an API where you can see the statistics of the app i.e. number of backups made, restores made, and the number of clusters connected to this application.

Now I want to send these stats to google analytics with an interval of 10 minutes. I was wondering if I can send the status to Event with a unique UUID as Event Category, the backup/restores, or nodes as Event Labels and the number as Event Actions.

Is this the right approach to using Google Analytics Events? Or is there a better way to do it in GA? My requirement is I have to do it in GA or should I use a different hit type.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we are talking API's you intend to use the Measurement Protocol?
And the UUID refers to the unique user? if so, you should look at the uid https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid

As to using Events versus Hits, using hits is probably easier on the reporting.